# How do I use the new binding in List with Swift 5.5?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying out the new feature in SwiftUI 3 (or, rather Swift 5.5), where you can have direct bindings to items in a List.
Should be simple, but I can't grasp it.

Xcode beta 4.

I can click on an item on the list, thereby activating the TextField. However, after entering one character, the TextField loses focus.

Simple example, I tried running it on both MAC and iOS, with the same result.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var items = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C"]
   
    var body: some View {
        List ($items, id: \.self) { $item in
            TextField("EditItem", text: $item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing the new update or you want solve your programing issue with it?

Comment: Never use ‘id: \.self’ it’s a serious mistake

Comment: @malhal why? If you have a hashable, unique value, why is it a "serious mistake"?

Comment: @jnpdx it leads to memory leaks because SwiftUI can't identify the matching data when the body is called again after a state change. The docs state id needs to be a property of the data so it shouldn't be the data itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are identifying the elements in the `ForEach` by using `\.self` so directly when you edit a string it gets a new identity since it is changed and then SwiftUI sees it as a delete of the object and insert of a new object rather than an update of the existing one.

When I try this with a struct that conforms to `Identifiable` it works fine because then SwiftUI can keep track of the changed object using the `id` property.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = [Item(name: "Item A"), Item(name:"Item B"), Item(name: "Item C")]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($items, id: \.id) { $item in
                TextField("EditItem", text: $item.name)
            }
            Text(items.map(\.name).joined(separator: " : "))
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this has most likely nothing to do with SwiftUI 3.0 or any beta but is more of an expected behaviour

Comment: Thank you so much, this totally makes sense!